# JQuery .css() function doesn't change all properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I'm creating a UI with sliding panels much in the fashion of this site: http://smithandhawken.catalogs.target.com/#/intro-cover

I have two ways to change the pages though, by column and by row.  The user can use the keyboard as well as some visual elements to navigate the pages.  The movement is handled by functions like this:

```
function moveDown()
{
unbindAll();
currentPage = 1;

$('div.section').each(function(index, element) {
    if(index+1 == currentSec) {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).css({ 'margin-top': 0, 'z-index': (storyCount-1)*100 });
        if($(this).next().size()) {
            populate(currentSec+1, currentPage);
            $(this).next().children('div.page').css('left', $(window).width());
            $(this).next().children('div.page').eq(0).css('left', 0);
            console.log(storyCount);
            $(this).next().css({ 'margin-top': $(window).height(), 'z-index': storyCount*100 }).stop().animate({marginTop:0}, 500, function() { 
                currentSec++;
                bindAll();
            });
        }
        else {
            populate(1, currentPage);
            $(this).parent().children().first().children('div.page').css('left', $(window).width());
            $(this).parent().children().first().children('div.page').eq(0).css('left', 0);
            $(this).parent().children().first().css({ 'margin-top': $(window).height(), 'z-index': storyCount*100 }).stop().animate({marginTop:0}, 500, function() {
                currentSec = 1;
                bindAll();
            });
        }
    }
    else if(index != currentSec) {
        $('#section'+(index+1)).css({ 'margin-top': 0, 'z-index': 100 });
    }
    });
}
```

THe line above that doesn't work the same way 100% of the time is - $(this).css({ 'margin-top': 0, 'z-index': (storyCount-1)*100 });

When the user uses the keyboard and the left/right visual elements, everything works fine.  When they use the visual elements that translate between each row (up/down methods only), the function fires, but not all CSS properties are applied.  Here is the function for the visual elements I'm talking about:

```
function mdlButton(btnHit)
{
btnLabel = btnHit.attr('id').substr(3);
console.log('enter first swtich '+currentSec);
switch(currentSec)
{
    case 1:
        console.log('enter second switch '+btnLabel);
        if (btnLabel == 1) {
            console.log('dont do anything');
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 2) {
            console.log('move down one');
            moveDown();
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 3) {
            console.log('move down two');
            moveDown();
            moveDown();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('enter second switch');
        if (btnLabel == 1) {
            console.log('move up');
            moveUp();
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 2) {
            console.log('dont do anything');
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 3) {
            console.log('move down one');
            moveDown();
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('enter second switch');
        if (btnLabel == 1) {
            console.log('move up two');
            moveUp();
            moveUp();
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 2) {
            console.log('move up');
            moveUp();
        }
        else if (btnLabel == 3) {
            console.log('dont do anything');
        }
        break;
}

if(!btnHit.hasClass('mdlSelected')) {
    $('div.mdlSec').removeClass('mdlSelected');
    $('div.mdlSec').find('#selected').remove();
    btnHit.addClass('mdlSelected');
    btnHit.find('div.divider').after('<div id="selected"></div>');
    reSize();
}
}
```

I can't figure out the reason why the z-index wouldn't change when called from the above function as opposed to just the keyboard or when left/right call the moveDown()/moveUp() methods.  Just in case, here's what the left/right look like:

```
function moveLeft()
{
unbindAll();
$('#section'+currentSec+' div.page').each(function(index, element) {
    if(index+1 == currentPage) {
        if($(element).prev().size()) {
            populate(currentSec, currentPage-1);
            $(this).animate({'left': $(window).width()}, 500, function() {
                currentPage--;
                bindAll();
            });
        }
        else {
            moveUp();
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Can't you make a jsfiddle from this? Would be much easier to answer.

Comment: A guess: `storyCount` is `undefined`, and jQuery does not assign `NaN`. Could you please break down the line that does not work?

Comment: NITPICK: Your coding style causes the code to run slower. Do not keep looking things up. Store a reference to them or use chaining. Basic example `var elem = jQuery(this); elem.css(...); var nextElem = elem.next(); nextElem.css(...); nextElem.eq(0).css(...); //or  jQuery(this).css(...).next().css(...).eq(0).css(...);`

Comment: storyCount is defined on pageload by it's own function.  The value is 3.  I'm working on creating a jfiddle for you, thanks.  And point taken on the coding :-p

Comment: I haven't gotten it to load properly in jsfiddle, but here's what most of the code looks like together. http://jsfiddle.net/9yAN8/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index was being reset back to another value by the reSize() function which was called to resize the footer buttons.  I've separated the resize functions and the problem disappeared.  No problems with the code itself, just the execution order.

Thanks for all the help!